Byte-Range Downloading for Presigned S3 URL
I have an application that downloads files from S3 via presigned URLs. The files range a lot in size from <1MB to >100MB. Currently, we just use Apache HTTP Client to download the object to a file which can take >30s.
I'm looking to optimize this operation by separating the download into byte-ranges which can be completed at the same time.
I saw that AWS provides a performant S3 client. Is it possible to take the presigned S3 link and create a GetObjectRequest using the link? You do need ListObject permissions for that request, so maybe this approach doesn't really work?
If using the AWS provided client isn't possible, what other libraries are possible to optimize the file downloading?

"Apache HTTP Client to download the object to a file which can take >30s" At the end of the day this is going to be limited by your internet throughput. S3 can send data really fast, but can your internet service provider and all intermediaries match that speed?

have you gzipped the file yet? Why do you need to download it? to seek into it? Please question your design, because storing a 100MB+ in any remote location without a way to access/index/search it without downloading it is a horrible oversight in design.
